# Xamarin : Can't create project with type monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am getting "Can't create project with type monodroid", on OS X Yosemite. I have just installed Xamarin. Not getting anything in the logs. I am using Xamaring Studio.

Comment: Have you looked in here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20644/error-cant-create-project-with-type-monodroid

Comment: @MilenPavlov I have gone through that thread. Does it have to anything with Android NDK? because I am seeing no tick mark for NDK in Xamarin Studio preferences.

Comment: I never used Xamarin.Android under OS X but assumed that there's a android component missing. I had some issues using their automatic installer previously, so my advice is to remove everything and do manual install: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/mac/manual_installation/

Comment: @MilenPavlov Thanks for the reply but I have already spent more time in downloading all the stuff. If I remove everything then again it will take a lot of time to download. I have posted the thread in Xamarin forums also. If it does not solve the problem, then I will remove everything and install it again.

Comment: @Kaustubh - You can download just Xamarin.Android and install that. That seems to be what you are missing on your machine. You can find a download to Xamarin.Anroid on your account page - https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads